# Counter for "Viewed"

Tags: discussion

I just posted a question and realised that every time I refresh my page to check whether there are new answers I increase the number of **Viewed** (i.e. how many times my article has been viewed). Wouldn't it be much more sensible to count only views from others users and not to count the views of the OP who posted the question?

Comment: In the `booster` badge description it says: "Shared a link to a question that was visited by 300 unique IP addresses" so it seems likely that the "viewed" counter is counting IP's (just a guess).  Is it possible that your IP changed between refreshes?  Possibly on a mobile device connecting via wifi?

Comment: @ScottH. I was loged into a wifi-network with my MacBook. I am not sure but I doubt that my IP changes every time I refresh the page. Maybe the IP is changed every 2 hours but this is something I need to check with my admin.

Comment: I have fixed IP and refreshing a questioh doesn't increase its number of views.

Comment: I must second John: I came here in some hours ago from an RSS link, and after reading I made a full refresh of this page – it increased by one. Further refreshes had no effect, though. Now, I jumped in again from main Meta.TeX.SE to see for more reactions. Again exactly one refresh increased the counter. My IP changes once a day or on reconnect, but this was not the case here. If it is important: User agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/17.0 Firefox/17.0".

Comment: Could it be that the counter was increasing because other people were visiting your page? How do you know it was increasing because of your refreshing?

Comment: @Vivi: This is possible, but, if you read my comment, in my case not very likely.

Comment: @T.Verron What about people that cannot fix their IP? Isn't it possible to count only once per user?

Comment: @John : Eh, I have no idea, I was just reporting my experience.

Comment: It seems like the view count ignores duplicate requests from the same user ID (if logged in) or IP address (if not logged in), within a ~15 minute window. If you visit again later in the day, it will count as another view. [See more discussion in this and other threads on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90187/134300).

Comment: @Forest I think that you should post that as an answer!